# C# calling a API endpoint with CSRF token its not working

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebrequest, csrf-token

I need to develop a .NET Job that triggers an execution in the HPOO software, by calling API endpoint that requires a CSRF token.

Before I started coding, I tested the scenario in Postman:

- calling a normal GET endpoint only with the basic authentication
- getting back a CSRF token
- and then finally calling a POST API, passing the basic authentication together with the CSRF token.

Everything worked as expected when I did these tests in Postman.

When I try to implement the same scenario in code, the program blocks when calling the POST endpoint (passing the token).

Follow my code below:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var uriExecution = new Uri("https://hpoo-api.com.br/oo/rest/v2/executions");
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriExecution);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + GetBasicAuthenticaton());
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

var response = request.GetResponse();

var csrf = response.Headers.Get("X-CSRF-TOKEN");

HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriExecution);
request2.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request2.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + GetBasicAuthenticaton());
request2.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrf);
request2.CookieContainer = cookies;

var response2 = request2.GetResponse();
```

At the moment my code calls the method `GetResponse()` of `request2`, I get a exception saying I'm forbidden to access (403).

I tried with `HttpClient` library too, but I got the same error, specifying that I'm forgetting the CSRF token.

Some things that I already tried which have not worked:

- Created a new `CookieContainer`, with all cookies in the first request, and pass to the request2.
- Removed the CSRF header, only cookies.
- Removed the cookies, only passing the header.
- Removed the CSRF header, only passing the CSRF query and cookies.
- Removed basic authentication, only passing the CSRF header and cookies.

Please, someone could help me? 
Sorry for my bad english, brazilian here...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Even colleting the cookies from first request and storing in a CookieContainer, the second request wasn't sending the cookies. After some search, I see its possible to send cookies in header, like this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2");
```

This way works like a charm, I only have to understand why using CookieContainer doesn't work...